# Rest error message in HTTP Header or Response Body?

Tags: http, rest, http-error

I have a REST service that is exposed to iPhone and Android clients. Currently I follow the HTTP codes 200, 400, 401, 403, 404, 409, 500 etc.

My question is where is the recommended place to put the reason/description/cause of the error? Does it make more sense for the REST API to always have custom Reason in the header like so?

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request - Missing Required Parameters.
< Date: Thu, 20 Dec 2012 01:09:06 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Or is it better to have it in the Response Body via JSON?

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Thu, 20 Dec 2012 01:09:06 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json
{ "error" : "Missing Required Parameters" }
```

Comment: Nowadays, it is a common practice to add custom headers, such as 'X-HTTP-Error-Description: Missing required parameters'.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Quoting from the HTTP specification for 400.x error codes:

> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client
>   seems to have erred. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
>   server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the error
>   situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. These
>   status codes are applicable to any request method. User agents SHOULD
>   display any included entity to the user.

It is best practice to include the error message as an entity in the body of the HTTP response - be it JSON, plain text, formatted HTML, or whatever other format you may want to utilize.

Answer (score 28):

It is better to have error details in the body. Furthermore, many (most / almost all, eg. WSGI) servers and clients do not support changing the name of the error code - treat them as fixed pairs (so eg. 400 is always "Bad Request" and not "Bad Request - You Forgot To Specify The User ID"). Even if they won't break, they won't care about your special name for specific error code.

Answer (score 4):

The error does not belong in the body. It belongs in the Warning header.

> The Warning general HTTP header contains information about possible
>   problems with the status of the message.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Warning)

Comment: Would be nice to use an "official" header for this. However, `Warning`, as the name suggests, is not for errors. The RFC (7234) says:
>The use of a warning, rather than an error status code, distinguishes these responses from true failures.

Comment: Note: The Warning header is soon to be deprecated; see Warning (https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/139) and Warning: header & stale-while-revalidate (https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/913) for more details.